# Logical except/difference ranges in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get logical `(A - B)` or `(A \ B)` in google spreadsheets.

So, having:

**A:A**

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

and

**B:B**

```
{2,3,5,6}
```

[image]

So my formula

```
=my_amazing_formula(A:A, B:B)
```

should return

```
{1,4}
```

(Elements of A not being present in B)

**The question**

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want to compare objects or arrays? {1,2,3,4} is not a valid method.

Comment: Are speaking in terms of ranges as describe in Range Class, or elements of arrays as in Javascript Arrays or Javascript Objects. Please explain question in more detail.

Comment: Hey @JakubKopyś have you managed to make this work with my answer? Please let me know if you have any other question/issue. Cheers

Comment: @Juan It's spreadsheet array notation. Both `{1;2}` and `{1,2}` are valid arrays  which are equal to JavaScript `[[1],[2]]` and `[[1,2]]` respectively.

Comment: You are right @TheMaster, I thought he wanted to define an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in there is no such data structure as a [HashSet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) in Google Apps Script yet, this is a somewhat tricky problem to solve efficiently. You can opt for the quadratic solution, which for each item in the first range would iterate over the whole second one trying to find a 'match', in order to discard it. This would look somewhat like @Cooper 's solution.

As an alternative, and considering that Google Apps Script's objects preserve property insertion order, you can use the following code which should theoretically yield better performance results (specially for larger workloads).

```js
function DIFFERENCE(range1, range2) {
  var o = {};
  for (var i=0; i<range1.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<range1[0].length; j++) {
      if (!o[range1[i][j]])
        o[range1[i][j]] = true;
    }
  }

  for (var i=0; i<range2.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<range2[0].length; j++) {
      if (o[range2[i][j]])
        o[range2[i][j]] = false;
    }
  }

  return Object.keys(o).filter(function f(key) { return o[key]; }).map(function(res) { return parseFloat(res) });
}
```

This function assumes that you are dealing with numbers. If you want it to work with strings as well, you can replace the last line of code by the following: `return Object.keys(o).filter(function f(key) { return o[key]; });`

You can also see a couple of examples here:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you elaborate your answer into a more generic approach that would let me know if there are any differences between sheets? Im looking into comparing entire spreadsheets, not just worksheets, but is proving quite tricky, and your approach seems educated and promising. It would not return the data diff, just true/false. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with inbuilt formula:

```
=FILTER(A1:A4,ISNA(MATCH(A1:A4,B1:B4,0)))
=FILTER({1;2;3;4},ISNA(MATCH({1;2;3;4},{2;3;5;6},0)))
```

- `FILTER` out A1:A4, where
- A1:A4 `ISN`ot `A`vailable in `B1:B4`

Answer (score 1):

If you question involves arrays then try this:

```
function elementsOfANotPresentInB(a,b) {
  var a=a||[1,2,3,4];
  var b=b||[2,3,5,6];
  var c=[];
  a.forEach(function(e){if(b.indexOf(e)==-1){c.push(e);}});
  Logger.log(c);
  return c;
}
```