# Comparing Spreadsheets Content

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to replace the content of one spreadsheet with another. This process repeats with several spreadsheets. I wanted to introduce a check: to save time and work, by avoiding the worksheet-by-worksheet deletion and copy, by checking first if there are any differences in the content between them.

However, I cant find any tools for that purpose on the API, and it seems that comparing the content requires more manual work than the original process anyway.

I thought about comparing dataRanges, using [Spreadsheet.GetDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getDataRange()) on each spreadsheet, however getting the dataRange on the spreadsheet actually returns just de dataRange from the first worksheet.

Is there any way to do this? Any sort of hash for the content of a spreadsheet that we can compare?

Comment: `Sheet.getDataRange.getValues();` for each sheet.  `Spreadsheet.getSheets();`

Comment: Yes, but that still requires manual comparing of values, iterating over the values. If that is what you mean. Is even more work than just deleting and copying the sheets.

Comment: Actually, I was just reading another question which may be of some use here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593542/logical-except-difference-ranges-in-google-spreadsheets

Comment: `it seems that comparing the content requires more manual work than the original process anyway.` I'd agree. Seems like a fruitless endeavor.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I just have to accept it, but was worth comparing notes with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already said, it would take more time to compare all the values in a sheet than just copying the content.

So I would just use [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet)) for each sheet in the origin to the destination spreadsheet and use [deleteSheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet(Sheet)) to remove all previous sheets in the destination.

Or depending on your requirements, [copy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String)) the full spreadsheet directly.

Comment: Thank you. The sheet by sheet process is precisely what Im doing. I cant copy the spreadsheet, as I need to respect a reference to the already existing file id.